# Configure Paypal Standard in Nop Commerce 2.60 But Website Payments Preferences option not found in sandbox.paypal.com

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce

I did not find the link of **Website Payments Preferences** in Paypal sandbox login.

Kindly send me the link of **Website Payments Preferences** in Paypal sandbox (**sandbox.paypal.com**) login account.

Because I want to be configure Paypal standard in NOP Commerce 2.60 version.

Please follow the below link for configure paypal standard in NOP Commerce 2.60

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/2064/how-to-paypal-standard-setup.aspx

Thanks,

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

The link should be within the profile of a Business or Premier account. It isn't called "Website Payment Preferences" anymore though - it's "Website Preferences".

Here is a direct URL to it:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

You need to be signed into a Sandbox account before  you can go there.